# How to Develop algorithms for linear search and binary search using Pseudo code.?

Tags: arrays, list, binary-search, linear-search

Searching on an array/list is to find a given element on the array and return whether it is found or not and return its position if found. Linear search and binary search are two popular searching algorithms on arrays.

- Define what an algorithm is and outline the characteristics of a good
  algorithm. Develop algorithms for linear search and binary search
  using Pseudo code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Algorithm**

An algorithmic program is a list of rules to follow in order to solve an issue. It is ordinarily used for processing, calculation and alternative connected computer and mathematical operations.

**The characteristics of a good algorithm.**

1. Finiteness: an algorithm should terminate infinite number of steps and each step must finish in finite amount of time.
2. Input:  An algorithm must have Zero or more but must be finite number of inputs.
3. Output: An algorithm must have at-least one desirable outcome.
4. Effectiveness: An algorithm should be effective means that each step should be referred as principle and should be executing in finite time.
5. Unambiguous:  Algorithm should be clear and unambiguous. Each of its steps, and their inputs/outputs should be clear and must lead to only one meaning.
6. Finiteness: Algorithms must terminate after a finite number of steps.

**Liner Search**

Linear search is a very basic and simple search algorithm. In Linear search, we search an element or value in a given array by traversing the array from the starting, till the desired element or value is found.
**Pseudocode for Liner Search**

```
Read size,array[size], search from user
    i=0
While i<size
        IF 
            search==array[i]
            write i
            break;
        Else
            i++
        Endif
Endwhile
```

**Binary search**

Binary search is the most popular Search algorithm. It is efficient and also one of the most commonly used techniques that is used to solve problems.

**Pseudo code for Binary Search**

```
Procedure binary search
   a← sorted array
   b← size of array
   c← value to be searched

   Set lowerBound = 1
   Set upperBound = b

   while c not found
      if upperBound < lowerBound 
         EXIT: c does not exists.
   
      set midPoint = lowerBound + ( upperBound - lowerBound ) / 2
      
      if a[midPoint] < c
         set lowerBound = midPoint + 1
         
      if a[midPoint] > c
         set upperBound = midPoint - 1 

      if a[midPoint] = c
         EXIT: c found at location midPoint
   end while
   
end procedure
```

Answer (score 1):

**Algorithm:-** Algorithm is a step-by-step procedure, which defines a set of instructions to be executed in a certain order to get the desired output.

1. **Linear search** is simply traversing whole array and searching it.
2. **Binary Search** is divide and conquer whole array and then search into it but the main condition is array needs to be sorted.

**Linear Search:-**

```
int arr[5] = {5, 3, 2, 6, 10};
int target = 6; // key to find in array
int result = -1;
for (int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++) {
      if (arr[i] == target) {
           result = i;
           break;
      }
}
cout << result << endl; // here is your result;
```

**Optimised Linear Search:-**
we can perform linear search in one more optimized way but need some more space
create an array with size 1 more than the given array for above example let it be 6
// then take input of user in same array and add key at last index of that array

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int arr[n+1];
for (int i = 0 ; i < n; i++){
    cin >> arr[i];
}
int target;
cin >> target;
arr[n] = target; // adding target
int result = -1;
int i = 0;
while(arr[i] != target){
    result = i;
    i++;
}

if (result == n){
    result = -1;
}
```

In above algo we don't need to add if always inside the loop we just need to check it at end.

**Binary Search:-**

```
// Binary Search 
int left = 0;
int right = arr.length() -1;

while(left <= right){
    int mid = left + ((right - left) / 2);
    if (arr[mid] == target){
        result = mid;
        break;
    } else (arr[mid] > target){
        right = mid - 1;
    } else {
        left = mid + 1;
    }
}
```

**Binary Search with Recursion:-**

```
   int binarySearch(int arr[], int left, int right, int target) {
        if (right >= left) {
            int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
            if (arr[mid] == target)
                 return mid;

            if (arr[mid] > target)
                return binarySearch(arr, left, mid - 1, target);

            return binarySearch(arr, mid + 1, right, target);
        }
        return -1; // didn't found the element
}
```